# A Greasemonkey script to make browsing interesting tags easier

Tags: discussion, tags, userscript

[SOFU Interesting Tag Browser](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/57763)

***Updated with bugfixes, see Recent Changes below.***
Thanks to those who responded with suggestions and bugs!

Wrote this for myself to make browsing my interesting tags easier in three ways.

[Screenshot http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/3602/interestingtags.jpg](http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/3602/interestingtags.jpg)

1. When browsing a single one of your "Interesting" tags,  shows previous and next buttons within the sidebar for **easy navigation to the previous and next interesting tag** in your tag list.  I find scrolling down to the "Interesting Tags" box and hunting for the next interesting tag I want to see to be a pain, this makes it very easy.
2. **Adds a "View All Interesting" link** to the siebar, which does an OR search on your interesting tags, effectively limiting your search results to ONLY questions having one of your interesting tags.
3. **Uses the tag name in the page header**, e.g. "Perl Questions" rather than "Tagged Questions" for tags you are viewing.  Works with "and" and "or" searches with multiple tags as well, but has a length-limit due to the layout of the site.  I prefer to display the tag I'm on in a bold, obvious way.

**Recent Changes:**

- Moved all links into the sidebar using native styles, giving a cleaner, more integrated look.
- Moving links out of the "Interesting Tags" area fixed the nasty bug that mangled your interesting tags when using this script.
- When adding or removing tags, the "Previous", "Next", and "View All Interesting" links are updated appropriately.
- When viewing stats pages or other tag pages with GET-style URL parameters, the heading rewrite now happens correctly.
- Limited the sites on which the script operates to SO, SF, and SU using the `@include` greasemonkey directive.
- Removed excess slash from the "View All Interesting" link.
- Added a "Case Correction" filter to the script, currently pre-populated with the most common tags on SO (first page of tags) which have non-standard capitalization schemes.  This makes it so that, for example, the mysql tag is rendered in the header as 'MySQL Questions' rather than 'Mysql Questions'.  To add more tags to correct, just edit the `caseCorrection` object at the top of the script.

**Still To Do:**

- Implement the trick [suggested by Rich Seller](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21717/a-greasemonkey-script-to-make-browsing-interesting-tags-easier/22301#22301) to utilize StackOverflow's included jQuery rather than the one from GoogleAPI.

Comment: It's better to activate it only on SOFU sites, not "//@include         *"
as it is now

Comment: The script adds an excessive slash to the url: "http://stackoverflow.com//questions/tagged/jetty+OR+usability"

Comment: Oh noes! The screenshot, she has disappeared!

Comment: @random: That's imageshack's fault, not mine.  It's being intermittent, like a romulan ship caught in phased space.

Comment: Is it just me, or has this stopped working recently?

Comment: Man, this question shows its age, containing _both_ a `userscript.org` and `imageshack.us` link. I tried to find this script on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/), but didn't have success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1, with a few observations from one Greasemonkey novice to another.

The styles for the Next and Previous stand out from the rest of the site, and using px values means they don't zoom well, you could try adding a div after the title, then appending the elements to the div with existing SOFU classes so they blend in.

There's no need to include jquery in your script, SOFU already include jquery.min.js, you can do something like this to wait for the page to load and obtain the jQuery variable (not my code, lifted from one of [Jonathan Sampson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/130154/jonathan-sampson)'s scripts)

```
(function() {
    function GM_init() {
        if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') {
            window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100);
        } else {
            jQuery_init(unsafeWindow.jQuery);
        }
    }

    GM_init();

    function jQuery_init($) {
        //your code here
```

Comment: ooh my first accepted answer on meta, thanks. Though it was only really an answer because it wouldn't fit in a comment.