# How to view only tags of interest?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filter view to show only interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested)

Is there a way on SO of seeing all questions associated with "interesting" tags? I find I switch between the 3 or 4 tags that I find interesting and it would be convenient to see all activity associated with my interesting tags on one page.

I know I can filter out ignored tags. But I want to filter out everything other than interesting tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently wrote a [greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21717/a-greasemonkey-script-to-make-browsing-interesting-tags-easier) for this exact reason.  It still needs a little work, but it makes switching among your interesting tags easier, as well as providing a link to do a tag search on only your interesting tags, from which *all* tabs (newest, featured, hot, votes, and active) are available to further refine your search.

Incidentally, that link is implemented by a simple URL:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1+OR+tag2+OR+tag3+OR+tag4
```

Note that any special characters in the tags must be URL-encoded.

Comment: The greasemonkey script has too many bugs for my liking -- it was generating bogus tags "show", "interesting", etc. However, the URL does the job perfectly. I've created a bookmark accordingly.

Comment: @Rob: Yeah, I was worried it would do that.  It stopped doing that for me after the last revision, but I guess it wasn't really solved.  I'll put a note in the OP.

Comment: Those bugs are now fixed.

Comment: It's working perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I have c++ in my list of interesting tags, but it isn't handled correctly by this script (the generated URL is e.g. java+or+c+++or+linux).  I tried encoding c++ as c%2b%2b, but this doesn't have any effect.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the SO engine - I have reported it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39201

Comment: See Jeff's reply: the script should use spaces, rather than '+' symbols, to delimit tags in the list.  This way it is robust against tags which themselves contain + symbols.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the Unanswered button, and then hit the MyTags tab to get all of your Interesting tagged questions that don't have upvoted answers, or you can go to this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions) and vote to get a button/tab created so that we can see all questions in our Interesting tags.

[image: Unanswered/MyTags]

Answer (score 0):

The only other way I can think of is for you to subscribe to the feeds of those interesting tags. Or open one tab on your browser per interesting tag. Or probably create a greasemonkey script for that purpose.