# how do i see questions which fall under my interesting tag?

Tags: feature-request

How do I see questions which fall under my interesting tags at one shot rather than clicking each tag ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in this question and its answers: [How to view only tags of interest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22338/how-to-view-only-tags-of-interest)

Comment: Thanks, it seems that such feature is not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Click the 'Unanswered' link. Then click the 'my tags' link.

Comment: Thanks, but wondering why does my interesting tag come under 'Unanswered' section ?

Comment: Because it only shows unanswered questions, not all questions in your tags.  It's not quite what you asked for.