# How can I see all the posts matching my interested tags?

Tags: support, questions, sorting, my-tags

I know how to see all questions matching to one tag, but how do I see all questions that match up with my set of interesting tags?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22338/how-to-view-only-tags-of-interest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I do

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash+OR+flex+OR+actionscript+OR+actionscript-3

Make a url matching your tags and bookmark it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in functionality for this, you'll have to use a userscript to achieve what you want.