# Show only "interesting tags" on a page

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filter view to show only interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested)
>   [Tab for interesting questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions)

SO already has an "interesting tags" feature setup, and you can simply look at any one tag.

It would be nice to display a page containing all of a user's interesting tags on a single listing.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36394/filtering-to-display-only-the-questions-tagged-with-an-interesting-tag http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25239/how-can-i-see-all-the-posts-matching-my-interested-tags http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22338/how-to-view-only-tags-of-interest

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22338/how-to-view-only-tags-of-interest http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested

Comment: I'm 28 seconds too late for `random`.

Comment: @random @Josh K: Doh! Sorry :(