# Make the 'Interesting Tags' heading clickable

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

As it stands I have a tiresome routine of clicking on each of my tags, check if there is a new question, then go back click the next one and so on.

I realise there are a few hacky ways of working around this issue, but in my mind it could be easily fixed by making the heading 'Interesting tags' clickable so that with one click it filters to all questions with one of my interesting tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions and see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46419/show-only-interesting-tags-on-a-page-closed for many more dupe links (it definitely gets requested quite often).

Answer (score -5):

I don't understand -- the "interesting tags" on the right hand side are in fact clickable. For example I have [bug] set up as an interesting tag here on meta. So on the homepage, I can just click the tag and I get the standard "questions tagged [bug]" page.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the heading 'Interesting Tags' rather than each individual tag. It would be nice to have one click that returned all interesting tags.