# Is should be possible to view a list of all questions with "interesting" tags

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-watching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filter view to show only interested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/filter-view-to-show-only-interested)
>   [How to view only tags of interest?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22338/how-to-view-only-tags-of-interest)

Highlighting interesting questions is nice, but it should be possible to ONLY list interesting questions.

I think the least intrusive way to do this would be to add a search option: `interesting:1`.