# Ignore what's not interesting

Tags: support, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Is there a way to set to ignore every tag which isn't checked as an interesting tag without actually manually adding every single possible tag to list of tags to be ignored?

Comment: Sort of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22338/how-to-view-only-tags-of-interest

Comment: Go vote for this feature request:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I'm afraid there isn't a way to do that.