# Can someone point me to information on how to use the SO site effectively?

Tags: discussion

Here's my specific question.

I'm interested primarily in .NET technologies. However, those technologies break down into quite a few tags, among them Silverlight, Silverlight 3.0, C#, C# 3.5, C# 4.0, XAML, .NET, .NET 3.5, LINQ, WPF, etc., etc, etc.

Would someone give me a walk though about how I'm supposed to find the questions that are of interest to me? I presume there is a better way than checking each tag individually? Is there really no better method then clicking on newest then an individual tag?

I'm also interested in other information on how to use the site effectively. The FAQ isn't very helpful in this, so any links you have would be appreciated. I'll do my best to upvote any answers that add information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Ólafur's suggestions, use Google as the SO home page.  Enter a search term in Google and use the "site:" search axis to limit it to SO.

```
c# .net site:stackoverflow.com
```

or

```
silverlight xaml site:stackoverflow.com
```

or

```
.net site:stackoverflow.com
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a few tips, hope they help.

- **Use the search options.** There is no specific rule for tag names, and there is tag [reorganizing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg-closed) going on. So finding all the tags you are interested in can be a challenge. 
  What does help is the search box. If you didn't know about the many cool options it has, then check it out [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=)
  You can also click "Ask Question" and use the tag box there as a search box for tags.
- **Related questions list.** A great way to find questions you're interested in besides tags, is the related questions list on the righthand side. Find a question you like and check there, and check that question's list.
- **The FAQ Tag.** Regarding on how to use the site effectively, check out the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) tag here. It has many great questions regarding the everyday usage of the site.

Answer (score 2):

In the right sidebar you have the option to set your interesting tags. They are highlighted for you then.

[alt text http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/2842/highlightspade.png](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/2842/highlightspade.png)

Also have a look at [this Greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21717/a-greasemonkey-script-to-make-browsing-interesting-tags-easier) to improve the handling.