# Is there a limit for max number of tags viewed at once?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-watching, views

I have a rather large list of interesting tags, and when i try to use a Greasemonkey extension (forget what it is) to view all of my interesting tags at once, i get an HTTP 400 request error invalid. So, what exactly is the limit for queries such as those?

Edit: [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21717/a-greasemonkey-script-to-make-browsing-interesting-tags-easier) is the extension.

Comment: Given that it may well be specific to the Greasemonkey extension in question, I suggest you find out which one it is.

Comment: If the problem comes from that script, why not just ask the person who wrote the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two syntaxes:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fun

and this:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=fun

The latter seems to be more tolerant of long URLs.

(and for completeness, there is also a synonym of the first, like so:)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/fun

Comment: it uses the first syntax. I'll see if i can edit the script to do it the other way and see if it helps though.

Comment: Modifying the script helped, thanks!